# Vertically expanded sub-nav in zurb foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Is this possible to have vertically expanded nav (menu with drop down) in mobile version of top bar instead of the default one (sliding in and out with back button)?
This could be accomplished by overriding the top bar methods, but maybe there is some other / simpler way...